# Get a number from HTML text when it contains a comma

Tags: html, jquery

I have a comma-separated number in my table. But my js on click gives only the values before the comma instead of the whole number.

```
<td class="amt">1,000,000.50</td>
```

Below is my jQuery that alerts `1.00` instead of the whole value:

```
$(".amt").click(function(){
   var t = parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2);
   alert(t);
})
```

This code alerts the exact figure but how can I get it as a number?

```
$(".amt").click(function(){
   var t = $(this).text();
   alert(t);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` to remove comma and `parseFloat` as

```
parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g,'')
```

```js
$(".amt").click(function(){
 var t = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g,''));
 alert(t)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="amt">1,000,000.50</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but before you try to convert the number string into a float using `parseFloat`, first you must remove all the commas from the string. You can do that using

```
textString.replace(/,/g, '');
```

Working Example:

```js
$(".amt").click(function(){
   var textString = $(this).text();
   var numString = textString.replace(/,/g, '');
   var numAsFloat = parseFloat(numString ).toFixed(2);
   console.log("Float value = "+numAsFloat);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amt">1,000,000.50</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Great insights. I'm very grateful